Java read several kinds of csv file into list
I've written below codes. I am wondering if there is better way of doing this.
My abstract class to read csv file.
public abstract class CsvFile {

public void readCsv(String csvString) throws IllegalAccessException {

    String[] csv = csvString.split(",");
    List<Field> fields = Arrays.stream(getClass().getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(f -> f.isAnnotationPresent(CsvProp.class))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(o -> Integer.parseInt(o.getName().replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++) {
        Field field = fields.get(i);
        try {
            field.set(this, csv[i]);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            field.set(this, "");
        }
    }
}

And classes that extends it.
    public class CsvType1 extends CsvFile {

    @CsvProp(name = "csvItem1")
    public String item1;

    @CsvProp(name = "csvItem2")
    public String item2;
}

public class CsvType2 extends CsvFile {

    @CsvProp(name = "csvItem1")
    public String item1;

    @CsvProp(name = "csvItem2")
    public String item2;

    @CsvProp(name = "csvItem3")
    public String item3;
}

And utility class to read file.
public class CsvUtils {
    public static List<CsvFile> readCsvFile(Class<? extends CsvFile> fileClass, String filePath) throws IOException, ReflectiveOperationException {
    List<CsvFile> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            CsvFile csvFile = fileClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
            csvFile.readCsv(line);
            list.add(csvFile);
        }
        return list;
    }
}

Usage:
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ReflectiveOperationException {
    List<CsvFile> f1 = CsvUtils.readCsvFile(CsvType1.class, "C:/csvfile1.csv");
    List<CsvFile> f2 = CsvUtils.readCsvFile(CsvType2.class, "C:/csvfile2.csv");

    for (CsvFile f : f1) {
        CsvType1 castedF = (CsvType1) f;
        System.out.println(castedF.item1);
    }
}

Is there a way to use it without casting by changing return type? I want use like this:
    List<CsvType1> f1 = CsvUtils.readCsvFile(CsvType1.class, "C:/csvfile1.csv");

for (CsvType1 noCastF : f1) {
    System.out.println(noCastF.item1);
}


Use
public static <T extends CsvFile> List<T> readCsvFile(Class<T> fileClass, String filePath) throws IOException, ReflectiveOperationException 

Also. Why not use existing library? Your is not proper csv parser.

I second using a library... there's all sorts of complicated rules that can trip you up.  (reading BOM, quote rules, line breaks in fields, etc.. etc.. etc..)

CSV is harder than it looks on the first glance.

Specification of all csv files are the same. It has been set by central government. we just follow it. No quotes, no line breaks, no headers, consider it wrong file if anything is wrong. I don't think I need csv library for this. Tell which type of the csv is by filename.
